# Inference on parameters estimated using optimization algorithm

Tags: optimization, inference

I don't have too much knowledge about mathematical statistics, so I would like to know how can I derive the confidence intervals and the distribution according a parameter(s) that was estimated using some optimization algorithm or numerical approximation with MLE.

For example, in the Spatial Auto-regressive Model I can derive the distribution of the vector beta using the estimator (a closed formula), but the auto-regressive spatial parameter is estimated using a numerical method, but I don't know how to derive the distribution according with the "estimator" in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically these sampling distributions are asymptotically multivariate normal, e.g. https://stats200.stanford.edu/Lecture14.pdf:

> The goal of this lecture is to explain why ... consistency and asymptotic normality of the MLE hold quite generally for many
>   “typical” parametric models, and there is a general formula for its asymptotic variance. The
>   following is one statement of such a result:
>   **Theorem 14.1**. Let $\{f (x|θ) : θ ∈ Ω\}$ be a parametric model, where $θ ∈ R$ is a single IID
>   parameter. Let $X_1 , \ldots , X_n ∼ f (x|θ_0 )$ for $θ_0 ∈ Ω$, and let $\hat θ̂$ be the MLE based on $X_1 , \ldots , X_n$ .
>   Suppose certain regularity conditions hold, including: 
>   • All PDFs/PMFs $f (x|θ)$ in the model have the same support,
>   • $θ_0$ is an interior point (i.e., not on the boundary) of $Ω$,
>   • The log-likelihood $l(θ)$ is differentiable in $θ$, and
>   • $\hat θ̂$ is the unique value of $θ ∈ Ω$ that solves the equation $0 = l' (θ)$.
>   Then $\hat θ̂$ is consistent and asymptotically normal, with 
>   $\sqrt{n}(\hat θ- θ_0) \to N\left(0, \frac{1}{I(θ_0)} \right)$ in distribution.

In particular, $I$ here is the *information matrix*, which you can estimate numerically from the second partial derivatives (e.g. by finite differences) of the log-likelihood function.